# Using dynamic keys in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, foreach, key, javascript-objects

I have the following javascript Object

```
const items = {
    0: {
        id: 1,
        color: 'blue'
    },
    1: {
        id: 2,
        color: 'red'
    }
}
```

I am trying to restructure it so that the keys have an indexed numerical value like so: **item1id**, **item1color**, **item2id**, **item2color**. Or to be more precise it should look like this in the end:

```
const restrucuturedItems = {
    item1id: 1,
    item1color: 'blue',
    item2id: 2,
    item2color: 'red'
}
```

I have tried the following, but so far didn't yield positive results:

```
const restrucuturedItems = {}; // should collect the restructured data in one object like so: {item1id: 1, item1color: 'blue', item2id:2, item2color: 'red'}
const restructuredData = Object.keys(items).forEach(key => {
    let i = parseInt(key, 10) + 1;
    let item = {
        item[i]id: 1, // this part is incorrect. it should produce item1id, item2id
        item[i]color: 'blue' // this part is incorrect. it should produce item1color, item2color
    }
    restrucuturedItems.push(item);
});
```

After hours of research, I still don't know how to write this part correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `push` because you want your `restrucuturedItems` to be an *object*, not an array.

Concatenate the `i` with the id or color *inside* the brackets, and use *two* `Object.entries` - one to get the keys and values of each object in the outer object, and one to get the keys and values of each *inner* object:

```js
const items = {
    0: {
        id: 1,
        color: 'blue'
    },
    1: {
        id: 2,
        color: 'red'
    }
}
console.log(Object.entries(items).reduce((a, [num, obj]) => {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    a['item' + num + key] = val;
  });
  return a;
}, {}));
```

If you really wanted to start at `item1id` rather than `item0id`, then increment `num` initially:

```js
const items = {
    0: {
        id: 1,
        color: 'blue'
    },
    1: {
        id: 2,
        color: 'red'
    }
}
console.log(Object.entries(items).reduce((a, [num, obj]) => {
  num++;
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    a['item' + num + key] = val;
  });
  return a;
}, {}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const items = {
    0: {
        id: 1,
        color: 'blue'
    },
    1: {
        id: 2,
        color: 'red'
    }
}
const restrucuturedItems = {}; // should collect the restructured data in one object like so: {item1id: 1, item1color: 'blue', item2id:2, item2color: 'red'}

const restructuredData = Object.keys(items).forEach(key => {
    let i = parseInt(key, 10) + 1;
    restrucuturedItems[`item${i}id`] = 1;
    restrucuturedItems[`item${i}color`] = 'blue'
});

console.log(restrucuturedItems)
```

First of all, you cannot use `push` onto an object. `push` is a method meant for array. Secondly, you can use template string with backtick to construct the property name that you wish

Answer (score 0):

a reduce and map function may do the job

```
var result = Object.values(items).reduce(function (r, val) { // get all the values
  var prefix = 'item' + val.id; // construct the prefix like item1, item2
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(val).map(function(key) {
    r[prefix + key] = val[key]; // add to the result object
  });
  return r;
}, {});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vw49g8t2/7/